# How to cancel/ abort pending cubejs api request

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch-api, cube.js

I am working with Cube.Js in react.
When i am changing the the route (Navigating to another page), I need to cancel the running request. How can we achieve this.
Do Cube.js has any provision to cancel pending API requests?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you include a code snippet of how you load the query results?